# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid parameter count for "REGEXP_REPLACE", expected count: "3..4"; SQL statement

Tags: java, h2

I'm just trying to test a query. I use h2 db. And there is a parameter limitation for REGEXP_REPLACE function. How can I create alias for this one? Because currently I have the following error:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid parameter
> count for "REGEXP_REPLACE", expected count: "3..4"; SQL statement.

As you can see I have 6 parameter.

```sql
regexp_replace(error,'(^.*)(date=.*)','\1', 1, 1,'m')
```

Answer (score 1):

`regexp_replace` - in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html) - can have up to 6 parameters:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE ( source_char, pattern
                 [, replace_string
                    [, position
                       [, occurrence
                          [, match_param ]
                       ]
                    ]
                 ]
               )
```

---

But, in [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#regexp_replace) (you use), it can have up to 4 parameters:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(inputString, regexString, replacementString, flagsString)
```

---

What to do? Adjust your code to syntax your database supports.

Comment: I guess it would be more wisely to create function for it.